# Show loading on clicking on a link, except for ctrl+click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a `<div>`that contains loading, using a tag-helper. I want to show the loading anywhere I have a `<a>` tag, except for `href='#'`. (I don't have any ajax call, so I will see a new rendered page after clicking the link)

```
  $('a:Not([class="NeedsConfirmation"])').click(function () {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var element = $(this);
    if ((element.attr("href") != "#") && (element.attr("href") != currentURL))
       {
        showLoading(element);
       }
  });
```

Now, I want to add additional exception: currently, If user presses the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then click the link, the new page will be shown but the previews page will show loading.

How can I discard calling  `showLoading(element);` in this case? (I have no problem with right-click and 'open in new tab' or window)

Comment: use the event object, it will contains the key modifiers `$('a:Not([class="NeedsConfirmation"])').click(function (event) {`

Comment: would you please explain it more?

Comment: I would recommand you to add `event.preventDefault(); `to each `a` tag click to prevent the element behavior and then use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events to show and hide the load div.

Comment: [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) the documentation to the event object, you have to check the `ctrlKey` property, @Amani the OP doesn't need ajax, he stated it in the first sentence.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano Thx ..Now I see.. I thought there is no Ajax Call only when the `href``proprety is empty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event-object passed into [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/). It has a property called `ctrlKey`. Check it and then do the stuff you want.

```js
$('a:not([class="NeedsConfirmation"])').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Check if ctrl was pressed...
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    // Ctrl was pressed during click
    alert('ctrl click');
    // Do something else.
  }
  else {
    // Ctrl was not pressed during click
    alert('not ctrl click');
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var element = $(this);
    if ((element.attr("href") != "#") && (element.attr("href") != currentURL))
    {
      showLoading(element);
    }
  }
});

showLoading = function(element){
  element.text('loading...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">click me!</a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">click me with link!</a>
```